# Java Comparing this.object to item object

Tags: java, oop, generics, compare

```
public int compareTo(T item) {
    int result = 0;
    if(this.zipCode < item) {
        result = -1;
    }
    if(this.zipCode.equals(item)) {
        result = 0;
    }
    if(this.zipCode > item) {
        result = 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How Can I compare a generic T item for a compareTo function?

```
public class Location<T extends Comparable<? super T>>  {

    private final String zipCode;
    private final String city;
    private final Double latitude;
    private final Double longitude;
    private final String state;

    public Location(String zipCode, Double latitude, Double longitude, String city, String state) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
        this.city = city;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.state = state;
    }
```

This is what my class looks like excluding getters and setters.

Edit: was able to fix it by making my objects generic but once i try to call it like here

````
    public static <T> void insertionSort(List<T> locations) {
          for (int j = 1; j < locations.size(); j++) {
              T current = locations.get(j);
                int i = j-1;
                while ((i > -1) && ((locations.get(i).compareTo(current)) == 1)) {
                    locations.set(i+1, locations.get(i));
                    i--;
                }
                locations.set(i+1, current);
            }
    }
    ```
I get The method compareTo(T) is undefined for the type T
````

Comment: Your class is not really generic since you don't use T anywhere. What is the point of it then?

Comment: Thank you, Now once i try calling it its giving me The method compareTo(T) is undefined for the type T

Comment: Your static method has no bounds on T

Comment: The T of your static method has nothing to do with the T of your class.

Comment: Incidentally, read the Javadoc for `Comparable.compareTo`, then consider whether `== 1` is correct.

Comment: That `compareTo` method looks very wrong on a couple levels: its type, the fact that it never actually uses `result`...